# React native css flex not working for android device

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

Don't hava a account?
              
                 Create new account.

[image]

```
   <View>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: "center", flexWrap: "nowrap", }}>
          <Text style={{ color: blue, fontWeight: "600", marginTop: 30, textAlign: 'center' }}>Don't hava a account?</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text style={{ color: blue, fontWeight: "600", marginTop: 30, textAlign: 'center' }}> Create new account.</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
```

Comment: Md Mahir , please provide some code for reference.

Comment: <View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row', alignItems: "center", flexWrap: "nowrap", }}>
              <Text style={{ color: blue, fontWeight: "600", marginTop: 30, textAlign: 'center' }}>Don't hava a account?</Text>
              <TouchableOpacity>
                <Text style={{ color: blue, fontWeight: "600", marginTop: 30, textAlign: 'center' }}> Create new account.</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>

Comment: What is the issue? Seems to be working just fine. You have `flexDirection: 'row'`, childs will be rendered in a row. Maybe you wanted to use ``flexDirection: 'column'`` in order to render them in on two lines aka in a column?

Comment: @peetzweg I want to flexDirection: 'row' , but when I apply this CSS ,       "Don't hava a account? Create new account."       text not showing